# How do I parse a map<String,Object>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing

I have a "Map<String, Object> values".
How can I parse this map so that I get a following string at the end?

```
String string= "key1 = value1, key2 = value2, key3 = value3, ..."
```

It is important that as soon as a value contains a string then it should be provided with single quotes.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

I need to expand my question.

So I need the string for a sql query. But the values which are strings have to be populated with SingleQuotes.

I show you my PostRequest method:

```
 @Transactional
    @PostMapping(value = "/config/test/{tableName}/{schemaName}")
    public Map<String, Object> postValue(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> values, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName,
            @PathVariable("schemaName") String schemaName) {
        String keyString = "";
        String valueString = "";

        Set<String> keySet = values.keySet();

        for (String key : keySet) {

            // add comma after first key-value pair only.
            if (keyString.length() > 0) {
                keyString += ",";
                valueString += ",";
            }

            keyString += key;

            Object valueObj = values.get(key);
            if (valueObj instanceof String) {
                valueString = valueString + "'" + valueObj.toString() + "'";
                ;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Integer) {
                Integer valueInt = (Integer) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueInt;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Double) {
                Double valueDouble = (Double) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueDouble;
            }
        }
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO " + schemaName + "." + tableName + "(" + keyString + ") VALUES(" + valueString + ")";
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return values;
    }
```

Here I get 2 strings. One for the keys and one for the values.

But now I want to get only one string to change data in the database.

Here is my first try.

```
@Transactional
    @PutMapping(value = "/config/test/{tableName}/{schemaName}/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> updateValue(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> values, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName,
            @PathVariable("schemaName") String schemaName, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        String keyString = "";
        String valueString = "";
        String updateString = "";

        Set<String> keySet = values.keySet();

        for (String key : keySet) {

            if (keyString.length() > 0) {
                keyString += "=";
                updateString += ",";
            }

            updateString += key;

            Object valueObj = values.get(key);
            if (valueObj instanceof String) {
                valueString = valueString + "'" + valueObj.toString() + "'";
                ;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Integer) {
                Integer valueInt = (Integer) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueInt;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Double) {
                Double valueDouble = (Double) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueDouble;
            }
        }

        final String sql = "UPDATE " + schemaName + "." + tableName + " SET " + updateString + " WHERE ID =" + id;
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return values;
    }
```

P.S. Yes I am using Spring Boot rather than Java, but I am trying to solve this without getting more dependencies.

Comment: I think the word "parse" is misleading here. You are looking for a custom method `toString()` (it doesn't have to be implemented in the class itself).

Answer (score 1):

I just use Guava, probably toStringHelper can help with this, for example

```
System.out.println(MoreObjects.toStringHelper("className").add("name","hoyt").add("age",11).add("job","writeBugs")
                .add("nullField", null)
                .omitNullValues().toString());

// this is the print
// className{name=hoyt, age=11, job=writeBugs}
```

you can iter through the map, and call add method, the return of the add method is the Guava object itself, so you can chain it.

```
MoreObjects.toStringHelper tsh = MoreObjects.toStringHelper("className")
foreach(Entry e : map){
    // add single quote if the value is a String,
    Object value = e.getValue();
    String valueString = value instanceof String?"'" + value.toString() + "'": value.toString();
    tsh.add(e.getKey().toString(), valueString);
}
// System.out.println(tsh.toString())
```

After UPDATE 1:

1. You should check the PathVariable String id, in case injection risks. For example if the value of String id is "12321 or 1 = 1", then after the update operation, the whole table would be updated.
2. Probably you can use oRM frameworks, for example JPA MyBatis hibernate, those are helpful and a lot of people use it
3. If you really just focusing on how to solve the problem only using java, of course you can do it with iterations and concat strings
4. Better use a StringBuilder for performance

Comment: you can check the type of value and change the code accordingly

Comment: yeah, every time "string" + "string", there are StringBuilder created underneath, and if one trying to "+" a lot of Strings, there are a lot of StringBuilders are created. If one use the StringBuilder, then there will only be one StringBuilder the whole time

Comment: right, I am not referring this post, I am referring to the original question. There is a loop there.             updateString += key;

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following example, you need to override the toString() Method

```
class TestObject {
  int val;

  public TestObject(int val){
    this.val = val;
  }

  public String toString(){
   return "" + this.val;
  }

}

Map<String, TestObject> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("First Object", new TestObject(1));
map.put("Second Object", new TestObject(2));
map.put("Third Object", new TestObject(3));

System.out.println(map.toString());// on printing map object
```

output: `{Third Object=3, First Object=1, Second Object=2}`

Further you can edit map.toString() output as follows

```
map.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
```

Comment: I actually tested in Jshell let me rewrite it

Comment: @user16320675 if quotes needs to be provided then you can add quotes in toString() method

Answer (score 0):

Stream based solution:

```
final Map<String, Object> values = Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3");
final var string = values.entrySet().stream().map(x -> x.getKey() + " = " + x.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(string);  // key1 = value1, key2 = value2, key3 = value3
```

Or you can simply use `StringBuilder` and iterate your `Map`.

Comment: Then implement `Object.toString` or simple wrap value in mapping.

Comment: `"'" + YOUR_STRING + "'"`?

Comment: > or simple wrap value in mapping.

Comment: @user16320675, what explanation do you need? Have you heard about SQL Injections and `PreparedStatement` to escape strings?

Comment: If you say so. Nevermind. Just ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParseMap {

    public static String getMapAsCustomString(Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(ParseMap::formatEntry)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }

    public static String formatEntry(Entry<String, Object> entry) {
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        return entry.getKey() + "=" + (value instanceof String ? "'" + value + "'" : value.toString());
    }

}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", 1);
        map.put("key2", "Two");
        map.put("key3", 7L);

        String string = ParseMap.getMapAsCustomString(map);
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 Thanks for the advice, updating the code

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Thanks for your support!

```
@Transactional
    @PutMapping(value = "/config/test/{tableName}/{schemaName}/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> updateValue(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> values, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName,
            @PathVariable("schemaName") String schemaName, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        String valueString = "";
        String updateString = "";

        Set<String> keySet = values.keySet();

        for (String key : keySet) {

            if (updateString.length() > 0) {
                updateString += ",";
            }

            Object valueObj = values.get(key);
            if (valueObj instanceof String) {
                valueString = "'" + valueObj.toString() + "'";
                ;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Integer) {
                Integer valueInt = (Integer) valueObj;
                valueString = valueInt.toString();
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Double) {
                Double valueDouble = (Double) valueObj;
                valueString = valueDouble.toString();
            }
            String keyValuePair = key + "=" + valueString;
            updateString += keyValuePair;
        }

        final String sql = "UPDATE " + schemaName + "." + tableName + " SET " + updateString + " WHERE ID =" + id;
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return values;
    }
```